# Codeigniter 3 check credentials on model?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, codeigniter-3

i'm using CodeIgniter 3 with Community Auth for Authentication. I want to restrict the database result based on the role.
Right now in the model the functions are like this:

get_finantial_report( some parameters, user_level, user_id)
and i get the user_level and user_id in the controller:

```
$this->auth_role
$this->auth_user_id
```

Would be better to remove those parameters (user_level, user_id) from the function and get them inside the funcion instead of passing them from controller to model?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch those variables in controller and do your validations on them and then send them to model for db stuff. 
Example:
For this there are two logic in my mind right now:
1- On base of `user_level` decide in controller whether you want to bring the result for this user or not.
e.g

```
if($user_level == 'something')
{
   $result = $this->model_name->get_finantial_report(some parameters, user_id);
}
```

2- Or after you have sent the `user_role` to the model there make a check on role whether you want to return the result or not.

```
function model_function(some parameters, user_level, user_id)
{
   if($user_level == 'something')
   {
      return $result = $this->db->query("// anything");
   }
}
```